# GIT: modify contents of the secondlast pushed commit

Tags: git

How I can modify the second last pushed commit using GIT,  I need to delete some files from the mentioned commit, and I would like to preserve the last commit.

What I did so far:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git reset --soft HEAD^   # two times

git reset HEAD .idea/  # and the same for other directories

git add -A
git commit --amend
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is a **`rebase`** to the commit you want to modify.

**Steps:**

1. Get the **commit ID** of the commit you want to modify.

   ```
   git log -2 // here '2' => will display last 2 commits
   // lets say the commit you wish to change has ID "ededeac"
   ```
2. Do an *interactive* **Rebase**

   ```
   git rebase --interactive ededeac // where "ededeac" is the commit to modify
   ```

   An editor will come up, with a list of all commits since the one you gave. 
   Change `pick` to **`edit`** for the commit needed to be modified.

   ```
   pick 8c27d78 fixed some bug
   edit ededeac fixed another bug // here, we changed pick to edit
   ```

   **Save** and exit. Git will then replay the listed commits.

   For each commit you want to edit, Git drops you into the shell. Then you can change the commit in any way you like.

   ```
   // delete/update files
   git commit --all --amend //here you can change the commit message too
   // The new changes are added on to the old commit
   // You can verify that with 'git log' and 'git diff HEAD^'
   git rebase --continue
   ```
3. **Force Push** to origin.

   ```
   git push origin --force-with-lease
   ```

   You need to force push to the origin since you are **rewriting history**.

Comment: in the second step : 
 `git rebase --interactive "hash of the 2 commit" ` 
in the editor I got only one  commit (which corresponds to the first commit, the second is not existing )
`pick 8c27d78 blabla`

Comment: @JaouharMbarek that's because you probably selected an incorrect commit ID. try `git log -10` to see your last 10 commits, then try again with the desired commit ID.