# Revert the committed to unstaged status

Tags: git

I prepare a project to employ on Heroku,
after `git add .` and `git commit -am "well prepared to deploy"`,
It come to me forgetting add `.gitignore` file.

How could I revert the committed to unstaged status.
`git reset` does not help.

Comment: try git reset Head~1

Comment: git reset --soft HEAD^

Comment: You could just run `git add .gitignore && git commit --amend --no-edit`. If `.gitignore` is also ignored, add `-f` to `git add`.

Comment: Could you please transmit the comment to answer. @ElpieKay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical usage scenario of `git commit --amend`, to amend the current commit with extra changes.

```
git add -f .gitignore
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

with `-f` to add ignored files and `--no-edit` to avoid launching the editor if the commit message doesn't need updating.