# How do i revert a commit and uncommit (?) a file?

Tags: git

My problem is that I can't push, because i accidentally committed a wrong file. 
Everytime I try to push i get FATAL ERROR: Forbidden file types detected: ... Main.class

I already tried reverting the commit, but I get the same error again. So how do I remove the file from commiting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead to do a `git reset @~`, to restore the index to the previous commit.
That won't touch your working tree (ie your files on your disk): only a `git reset --hard` would do so.

From there, you can add again your files, except this time, do exclude any `.class` file (ideally through a `.gitignore` file with a `*.class` in it)