# Amending the commit added on github

Tags: git, github

On my branch I've got 3 commits. Commits A and B were done from command line, commit C directly from github. How can I amend the message of commit C? I cannot do that directly on github but for some reason I cannot see commit C in history when running `git log` (I got only A and B in the results). Also running `git rebase -i origin/master` lets me ammend only commits A and B. I run `git pull` after adding commit C but that didn't do the trick. What's the proper way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Comment: @Makoto that's totally different case. My commit I want to amend was not made locally.

Comment: I disagree.  Amending commits is a fairly well-defined process and the answerse you're going to receive aren't going to diverge from what's in the dupe.

Comment: *Commits A and B were done from command line, commit C directly from github.* How did you create command C? That is, did you click on a "merge pull request" button, or what? (Not directly relevant to answer, but useful for knowing what you were doing in general.)

Comment: @torek, when you view the file on github you have the "edit" button that let you make changes and then, below, you can either add it as a commit to the current branch or create new branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna assume you know what you're doing and want to intentionally amend the commit from the remote, which in practice is gonna be a destructive operation (delete the old, add the new and generate missing refs to anyone working based on that commit). That said, it's pretty straightforward.

Pull their change with the problematic commit:

```
git pull
```

Apply your fix and amend it locally:

```
git add .
git commit --amend
```

Force push to your remote

```
git push -f
```

Let everyone who works under this repo that you did that so they can fix their missing refs.

Comment: Thanks. Strange as I run the git pull and that didn't work. But it was already late.

Comment: BTW: it's safer to use --force-with-lease instead of simple --force ;)

Comment: Interesting, I actually didn't know about --force-with-lease... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just fetch on your local, `git checkout` the remote branch, `git commit --amend`, `git push -f origin HEAD:remote-branch-name`. That should be enough

Comment: what's the difference between `git pull` and `git checkout`? Looks like that's where I am lost.

Comment: And no, unfortunately after checkout still my git history doesn't see that commit made on github :/

Comment: actually, they are quite different. `git pull` is more or less `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. It merges the branch that the branch you checked out is tracking (my guess, I'm not fond of pull because it does 2 things when I normally want to control step by step.... me, a control freak, I guess). `git checkout` is, well... start working somewhere else.

Comment: And fetch runs fine? And the revision you are trying to amend is the tip of a remote branch on that repo? And you don't get that remote branch updated when fetching?