# Change local git message for previous commit

Tags: git

I have a a ***local, unpushed*** branch of a git repo.
I am blocked from pushing my branch to origin cause I forgot to add in a ticket number in one of my git commit messages, so I can push to our master branch due to a restraint from our ticket integration.

The commit missing the ticket number is 3 commits pass my local branch head.

I've tried purposefully detaching at the commit to use `--amend`
but it did not work.

I've also tried to `cherry-pick` and `--amend` but that also did not work.

I've tried to do:

```
git reset [missing ticket # commit hash] 
git commit --amend
```

and tried:

```
git cherry-pick [missing ticket # commit hash]
git commit --amend
```

Neither work.

Comment: Try an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i).

Comment: eg `git rebase -i HEAD~10` (pick a number > 3).  Change the first column of the appropriate commit to `r`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify existing, unpushed commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commits)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+commit+message

Answer (score 3):

You have do a [rebase with interactive option](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). I.e:

```
git rebase --interactive HEAD~2
```

Then for the commit you want to change the message, choose the `reword` option.

Comment: Found my answer already, but thanks! For anyone else `HEAD~2` is specific to my case where the commit was 3 ahead.

Answer (score 2):

Just read a blog online to help. 
Was pretty dense and seemed outdated so I was very nervous of it.

But it worked.

```
git rebase --interactive [hash of parent commit]^
```

the carrot means to use as a parent and for every commit after it

then you'll be in some editor.

**Change the word `pick` to one of the commands, in my case it was `edit`**

*Very important to do the instructions above. I was confused on how to edit. It's a simple text change.*

Then you can use

`git commit --amend`

`git rebase --continue`

and now you should have the proper commit message.

[Helpful link](https://croisant.net/blog/2008-06-22-git-tip-fix-a-mistake-in-a-previous-commit/)

TLDR:

```
git rebase --interactive [hash of parent commit]^
```

*Edit `pick` on commit you want to change to `edit`*

```
git commit --amend

git rebase --continue
```

Comment: Note that "reword", if available, is much simpler. (It's not in some truly ancient Git versions, where you have to use the longer method that you used.)

Comment: so `git reword [commit hash]` ? I have `2.17` and it was not there, unless that's not the proper way to use `reword`

Comment: It's an option during `git rebase -i`: change `pick` to `reword` instead of `edit`, and your next step is to fix the message—there's no faffing about with `git commit --amend` and `git rebase --continue`.

Answer (score 1):

With `--amend` flag you can change last commit message, e.g. `git commit --amend -m "new commit message"`.
If you need to edit multiple commit massages use `git rebase -i`.