# Can I amend commits instead of making a new one and rebasing/squashing?

Tags: git, github

To edit pull requests while keeping the number of commits the same, I've been adding new commits and rebasing/squashing them, but I was recently told that you can just amend commits and achieve the same thing...how might I do this?

I've only been able to find stuff on how to change the commit message, not update the commit itself

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commit-messages

Answer (score 1):

When you `git add file` you then `git commit --amend` It should work. This seems to be very good documentation: [amend](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history)