# How to add files to commit which is already pushed to remote repository

Tags: git, github

I have commited the code (commit_id - ABC123) and pushed to remote repository.

I forgot to add some css files.

Now I want to add those files to the same commit (ABC123) without creating a new commit on remote repository.

Comment: You cannot. You can replace an existing commit but cannot modify it in place.

Comment: You will be creating a new commit and rewriting history. Not good for a repository shared with others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify existing, unpushed commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commit-messages)