# Change history of pushed, but not yet merged commits

Tags: git

After working on a task for a couple of days, I realized that I referenced the wrong ticket number in my commits. Now they already pushed to the server, the server doesn't allow altering of commmits, but since it is not merged into master, I wondered if I still have a chance to change it.
Maybe moving it all to a second branch and changing it there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to modify existing, unpushed commit messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commit-messages)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+old+commit

Answer (score 1):

You can use [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History): `git rebase -I HEAD~10`. You will get the list of last 10 commits. You can set `reword` for each commit and change to commit message.

Then you need to push changes to remote branch using: `git push --force-with-lease`.