# git push error(does not match the regular-expression)

Tags: git

```
remote: Start Git Hooks Checking                        [FAILED]
remote: Error: Deny by project hooks setting 'default': message of commit '33e095953ba928dc6e8dba98967c325fa8f5ba13' (see it by 'git log') does not match the regular-expression '(RR|IR|US|BUG|VUL)(\d{13,14})|(TX|WI|DTS)(\d{13})|(DTS[a-zA-Z0-9]{19})|(SR)(\d{14})|(#)(\d+)'.
To ssh://xxxx.com:1111/xxxx/xxxx.git
! [remote rejected]   feature_install_arch -> feature_install_arch (pre-receive hook declined)
```

what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your repo has some constraints about the commit messages it accepts. You need to match some regex `(RR|IR|US|BUG|VUL)(\d{13,14})|(TX|WI|DTS)(\d{13})|(DTS[a-zA-Z0-9]{19})|(SR)(\d{14})|(#)(\d+)`
See https://regex101.com/r/N7mU1w/1 to play and see what matches.

Ask your collaborators on what exactly is the logic there, and see previous commit messages for examples. To change a commit message after it was commiter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commit-messages)