How to change old git commit message before push with out git reset
I was working on git and found that the name under my old commit message was wrong.
It takes a lot of effort to change it using git reset head~1.
I haven't pushed it yet.
I tried to use git commit --amend, but when I go to the commit and enter this command, an editing window appears, but I don't know how to save it.
Please help.
I checked out the git commit I wanted to change.
Then I typed git commit --amend.
The editing window came up, so I tried to delete the original git name and save it, but I don't know how to save it.

Which terminal are you using? On which OS? Which editor is it?

I am using windows 10, so I used cmd.

Just do  git commit --amend -m 'the message I really want'

@eftshift0 It should be changed latest commit.
I want to change old commit message.

If with old you mean a commit that is somewhere before the last commit you are working on, then you can do git rebase -i the-commit-i-want-to-modify~ (make sure to include the pigtail), when you get the list of commits to work on, the commit you want to modify should be the first one, change the action from pick to reword, save and exit.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179123/how-to-modify-existing-unpushed-commit-messages Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+change+old+commit+message

@phd he is asking to chagne old commit message not unpushed message

@0xn0b174 I see "before push" in the title. And the answers at the duplicate question answer all possible scenarios — the last commit, old commits, pushed, not pushed…

probably its vim or vi , you just need to enter esc  then shift + ; and type 'wq' and hit enter. please try and check the vim tutorial in freecodecamp .
update:
you need to find the commit which you want to update comment
HEAD =  hash of the commit
git rebase -i HEAD

it opens interactive mode to modify your commit for eg:
pick 123abc First commit
pick 456def Second commit
reword 789ghi Commit you want to change
pick 101jkl Fourth commit

change pick to reword for commit which you want to change
hit ctrl + x and y and hit enter
now it will open the commit that you want to change
edit your commmit and exit with ctrl + x and y and hit enter

Yeah, It seems like save in vim.
But it is made new commit.
I want only change git message.

ah ok let me update the answer

Changing the commit message changes the commit.

really, i dont think so, i tried changin multiple times the hash remains same
